# How do I get the feathers?

Tags: angry-birds

I've completed the first 13 levels with 3 stars, and at the end of each one there is a partially transparent feather.  Also, at the stage select there seems to be a counter for feather of that stage just under the counter for stars.

I am wondering how you get this feather.  Do you need an even higher score or is it a unique requirement in every level?

Comment: I should point out that how you purchase the Mighty Eagle upgrade (or if it is even an upgrade) varies greatly depending upon where you are playing Angry Birds.

Comment: @JasonBerkan i'm playing it on an iPad in Australia

Comment: Then the Mighty Eagle is a one time In App Purchase that permanently unlocks the Mighty Eagle in the game, exactly as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain the feather, you first need to purchase the Mighty Eagle upgrade.  That unlocks the Mighty Eagle, which you can use to perform massive destruction in any level.

Using the Mighty Eagle automatically completes the level, and the feather is filled up based upon the number of points you scored.  If you do enough damage and get enough points, the feather is filled to 100% (Total Destruction) and the feather is shown on the stage select for that level.

The Mighty Eagle can always be used on levels you have completed, and it can also be used to bypass levels that you find difficult, though this use is on a timer - you can only use the Mighty Eagle to skip a level once an hour.

Answer (score -4):

You use the guest bird beginning of the level when u Pick your character to play with

Comment: Hi Donna. Welcome to Arcade! I didn't downvote, but I do recommend that when adding your answer, it should contribute information that isn't already addressed by an existing answer. This applies especially when there is already an accepted answer. Your answer is also very vague and brief to the point that it is incomplete and doesn't fully answer the question.